# From what chapter of the Nisekoi manga should I begin reading to pick up where the anime ends?

Tags: nisekoi

Finished watching the first 24 episodes of the series, want to continue the story reading the manga, where should i begin?

Bonus question!
What am I missing if I just skip to the chapter from the OP question?

---

EDIT: at the time of the original posting of this question, it was uncertain if they would continue the anime series. As of the spring/2015 season, Nisekoi was featured, and new episodes will push the story further.

Comment: Please specify the series you're talking about

Comment: It's tagged Nisekoi, not really a need to mention the title with the tag there.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer since only 5 books of the manga are out in English... however, the anime does skip over a few events of the manga. So reading from the beginning could be beneficial if you wish to know the whole story. Other than that, the anime covers the main parts, so skipping to where the anime left off won't leave you in the dark.

Comment: FYI, there is going to be a second season coming out some time in 2015 (assuming no Shaft delays), so if you prefer watching anime over reading manga, you won't have very long to wait for more content.

Comment: @senshin since the spring/2015 season is confirmed and already airing, I updated the question to restrict its scope to the first season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some differences between the manga and anime. This is some of the chapters that do not appear in the anime:

- **Chapter 7: Handmade.** This chapter tells about Raku and other girls bake a cake together.
- **Chapter 19: Visiting the Ill.** This chapter tells about Raku that got sick and all the girls went to visit him at home.
- **Chapter 26: Detour.** This chapter tells about Tsugumi that got a love letter.
- **Chapter 40: Liar.** This chapter tells about Tsugumi and her lie detector.
- **Chapter 41: Stray Dog.** This chapter tells about Chitoge found a stray dog.

All of those chapter are just filler. You still be able to follow the story without reading it. The anime, however, ends in **Chapter 50: Leading Actor**.

So, if you want to continue the story from season 1 of the anime, you should read **Chapter 51: From Here on Out.** But I suggest you also read chapter 50 to get the right feeling.